# Nearley parser grammar for parsing opening and closing tags

Tags: javascript, parsing, nearley

Say I had a simple language to parse in nearley that's just made of strings. `"this is a string"`

```
string -> "\"" chars "\""
```

However, that string can contain a code within curly braces. To keep things simple let's just say the `code` can only be another string.`"this is a string with {"code"}"`

```
code -> "{" string "}"
```

How do I define the new string in Nearley to include the `code` definition? I keep ending up with a huge number of results as `chars` can match one or more characters.

```
string -> "\"" charCode "\""

charCode -> (chars | code) charCode
| (chars | code)

code -> "{" string "}"

chars -> char chars
| char
char -> [^{}]
```

Ideally I'd be able to turn something like this `"chars {"code"} chars chars {"code"} chars"` into an array `["chars ", "code", " chars chars ", "code", " chars"]`

Perhaps it's only possible to do this using regex and moo as suggested in this answer? (The opening and closing tags are less ambiguous in this example, and I'm not experiencing the same issues.) [[Nearley]: how to parse matching opening and closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66538876/nearley-how-to-parse-matching-opening-and-closing-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regex-based lexer, certainly. But you could try to write an unambiguous grammar, based on the observation that you can never have two adjacent `chars` in a `charCode`:

```
string -> "\"" charCodeStart chars:? "\""
charCodeStart -> 
               | charCodeStart chars:? code
```

Another possibility, using EBNF:

```
string -> "\"" ( char:* code ):* char:* "\""
```

You'll probably have to play with that a bit to get it right. I don't use nearley much.

Comment: Thanks a regex lexer does seem to make it less complicated. I'll give it a go!

Comment: What does the `?` syntax do by the way? I can't find much of an explanation beyond it defining a "special sequence"

Comment: @ryan: it might be a mistake. :-( I was thinking `chars?` meant "an optional `chars`".

Comment: oh I not sure nearley can do optional items but maybe `char:*` (none or many) does the trick there. I've been looking into lexers and they seem to make things significantly easier - so I might head in that direction regardless.

Comment: @ryan: yeah, it should have been `:?`. Sorry about that. `char:*` would be a good one too

Comment: But lexers definitely make life easier.